# Ctrl-C en UNIX ¿?¿?

Tags: unix

Mi pregunta es la siguiente: ¿Por qué en UNIX si pulso Ctrl+C para terminar la ejecución de un programa, hay ocasiones en que sigo obteniendo la salida del mismo? Esto es, no me refiero a las situaciones en que la interrupción SIGINT, provocada por Ctrl+C, se maneja mediante código, si no a las ocasiones en que se realiza la pulsación y el programa no termina de inmediato, pero sí después de un tiempo.

Imagino que se debe a un retraso en el buffer de teclado en UNIX o a que el buffer de teclado está ocupado pero la verdad no puedo asegurarlo ni comprendo este efecto.

Agradecería mucho me lo explicaran. Saludos!

Comment: Hola Anita, ¿puedes incluir un programa de ejemplo para ilustrar la pregunta? Tal y como está redactada parece algo amplia. Lee [ask] para más información y consejos.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por responder! No me refiero a las ocasiones en que la señal SIGINT, enviada por Ctrl C es manejada o ignorada por el programa, por ello que no se indicar un código para ilustrarlo. Pero me refiero a las ocasiones en que, durante un tiempo, se sigue ejecutando el programa tras pulsar Ctrl C, y tras ese tiempo, ya si se interrumpe. Es decir, que el efecto de la pulsación no es inmediato ¿A qué puede ser debido esto? Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: Intuyo que tiene que ver con los retrasos de buffering en UNIX pero la verdad es que no lo comprendo. Si alguien me lo pudiera explicar, se lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: Deberías editar la pregunta para añadir esos detalles. La parte del buffer de salida es la seguramente la respuesta (corta) a lo que tienes ahora y quieres que se explique cómo funciona (que sigue siendo algo amplia).

Comment: Editada. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Esto sucede por que una de las acciones a seguir de esta señal es:

- El proceso puede detenerse después de un tiempo, después de liberar recursos.

Esta señal es bastante similar a `SIGTERM` que como mencionas puede ser manejada, ignorada o capturada la diferencia radica en que `SIGINT` puede ser enviada por el usuario a través de `ctrl + c`. Entonces cuando el proceso recibe esta señal puede ocurrir alguna de las siguientes situaciones situaciones.

- El proceso termina inmediatamente.
- El proceso puede detenerse después de un tiempo, después de liberar recursos.
- El proceso puede seguir corriendo indefinidamente.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por responder. Pero entonces, ¿puede que pase una de esas 3 cosas sin más? Es decir, puede terminar inmediatamente, seguir de manera indefinida o detenerse después de un tiempo, ¿de manera aleatoria? ¿Entonces no tiene nada que ver con el buffer de teclado ni con nada más? La verdad es que pensaba que SIGTERM si era para apagarlo de manera amable (liberar recursos y demás) pero que SIGINT era una interrupción y si no funcionaba era por algo más.

Comment: No hay por que para eso estamos :). Puede que se de uno de esos 3 casos (no de manera aleatoria), esto dependerá de qué instrucciones se tengan programadas para manejar la señal en la mayoría de los programas se libera recursos antes de terminar el proceso. Para el tercer caso imagina que el proceso tenga que escribir algo en disco pero por el momento no pueda, al recibir la señal sabrá que tiene que terminar pero no lo hará de inmediato o por lo menos no hasta que realice la tarea que pendiente.

Comment: Hola de nuevo, gracias por responder pero no lo entiendo bien, ¿CTRL-C no provoca SIGINT que es una interrupción en el programa? ¿Cómo va a esperar a terminar lo que está haciendo si se le envía este tipo de interrupción?

Comment: Pues **si** es una señal de interrupción pero al igual que `SIGTERM` puede ser manejada y en tal caso se puede dar alguna de las situaciones que menciono arriba. No es como `SIGKILL` que no puede ser manejada y termina el proceso inmediatamente.